# How to enable  fingerprint  device for Thinkpad t430s  in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I followed different tutorials to enable fingerprints reading, but without luck.

**Fingerprint GUI** keeps saying `no device found`.

Any help on this?

= Edit Following first answer =

I followed the tutorial you posted to install the fingerprint

the result of lsusb is :

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 17ef:1003 Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2020 Upek 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b2da Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f2:0760 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Acer KU-0760 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
```

So it doesn't seem that my reader is supported... am I right ?

Comment: I believe that the Upek 147e:2020 does not yet have a linux driver. http://darkblue.homeip.net/fingerprint/Forum/topic.php?TopicId=241&Posts=2

Comment: I retract my previous comment.  See post by @bender below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay I'm running a Thinkpad X1 and the same biometric chip is on it. I searched the whole internets **twice** for this problem, but, good news, I found a way to make it work in all cases, so here's a small "tutorial" that compiles the info from this thread and other places:

## Installing the software

First, add the fingerprint PPA as mentioned by the previous posts, and install the required packages:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
```

Then, download and untar this http://volker.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/BSAPI_4.3.291Lite_SDK_for_Linux.tar.gz.

## Modifying libbsapi

Libbsapi's PPA currently does not really support this chipset, however, replacing the install's with the latest version will work. **First, figure out you architecture (32 or 64), and then locate the libbsapi.so file in either the lib folder (for 32 bit) or the lib64 folder (for 64 bit)**. Then, **copy this file (using sudo, or gksudo on nautilus) to the /usr/lib folder.**

Then, we have to make an addition to this file: /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libbsapi.rules . The code do be added is:

```
#Added for Upek 2020 support
ATTRS{idVendor}==”147e”, ATTRS{idProduct}==”2020″,   SYMLINK+=”input/touchchip-%k”, MODE=”0664″, GROUP=”plugdev”
ATTRS{idVendor}==”147e”, ATTRS{idProduct}==”2020″,   ATTR{power/control}==”*”, ATTR{power/control}=”auto”
```

Do it using either : `sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libbsapi.rules` or `sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libbsapi.rules`, whichever you might prefer.

## Last modification and it's all done

We have to grant fingerprint-gui access to the reader's USB bus. Run `lsusb` and locate the line that may look like this `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek`  (actually look for the 147e:2020 Upek ID). 001 here indicates its bus id, and 003 is its Device id. Note yours. Then, issue the command (in my case, but adapt to your own bus and device id's):

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
```

Then, start fingerprint-gui, and it should recognize your device, and configure it happily.

Comment: actually there's a small problem: whren Ubuntu reboots, it resets the permission code for the USB bus to something else, so the fingerprint prompt still appears but can't activate the hardware... any idea on how to fix this? Maybe instead of chmoding the bus, we could add fingerprint to some user group that has some power over this?

Comment: It does not work for me as any other solution found in web. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 on Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon. The problem is that my fingerprint device is not even listed afer runing lsusb. Any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: Does it work on windows? If it doesn't, the device itself might be defective.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there is a newer version of `libbsapi` available than is packaged in the `fingerprint-gui` PPA that supports this device. I've tried it out with my T530 (scanner deviceid 147e:2020) and it works.

There is an instruction and a source for this lib on [this page](http://volker.de/tag/upek-147e2020/) (scroll down on linked page for the English version). On my Ubuntu 12.10 setup, the path to the `udev` rule file that has to be edited is different from the one in the tutorial, it is:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libbsapi.rules
```

Comment: This worked well for me.  Thanks for pointing this out. I've been waiting on this for several months.

Answer (score 3):

```
Supported readers (run command lsusb to find out the ID of your reader)
============
  045e:00bb        061a:0110        147e:1002
  045e:00bc        08ff:1600        147e:1003
  045e:00bd        08ff:2500        147e:2015
  045e:00ca        08ff:2580        147e:2016
  0483:2015        08ff:5501        147e:3000
  0483:2016        138a:0001        147e:3001
  05ba:0007        147e:1000        147e:5002
  05ba:0008        147e:1001        147e:5003
  05ba:000a
```

## **Installation**

1. First of all, if you have installed Fingerprint GUI manually before, get rid of it completely. Remove all binaries, shared libraries, any other files and undo all the changes you have made to your system config files (especially to files under /etc/pam.d/).
2. Add this PPA to your sources:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui
   ```
4. Log out of your session and log back in (we need the new session defaults to be picked up).

## **Setup**

After installation launch Fingerprint GUI (can be found under System > Preferences) and enrol your fingerprints.

That should be all you need to do!

Try locking your screen, logging out and in, sudo in terminal and running graphical apps requiring root privileges.

Comment: I edited my question... is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Have you tried the method above?!

Comment: This method is how I installed fingerprint in the first place... but since my reader is not in the list of supported reader you posted, doesn't it make sense that it doesn't work?

Comment: Sure if your reader ID is not listed in the list sure it will not work, anyway let me seacrh for a solution to your IDs

Comment: Thanks! I guess it'd be good for fingerprint gui to add it to its supported devices... :p

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct 2013, the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui) was updated and this worked out of the box for me.  I am using Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy) with a Thinkpad T430s (Upek 147e:2020). The PPA page shows a much larger list of supported devices now.

I never used fingerprints much on my old T60 because it was such a pain to set up, but I am really liking it now.

Answer (score 0):

**Fprintd**

Fprintd is in Official Ubuntu Repository.

It also provide drivers as well.

Can be installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install fprint-demo fprintd fprintd-doc libpam-fprintd libfprint0 libfprint-dev
```

[image]