# How do I get the fingerprint reader to work on a Lenovo x230 Tablet?

Tags: drivers, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I followed this post: [How to enable finger printer with Thinkpad X230](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197336/how-to-enable-finger-printer-with-thinkpad-x230/219257#219257)
and tried to install software support for my fingerprint reader. But the software does not find it.

This is the message when i want to setup the Fingerprint Reader:

"ThinkPad-X230-Tablet:~$ fprintd-enroll
list_devices failed: No devices available"
Do you know ho to fix this issue?

And here is the result from `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bdb:1911 Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 056a:0090 Wacom Co., Ltd TPC90
```

I hope you can help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Exactly the same device in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/193528/how-to-enable-fingerprint-device-for-thinkpad-t430s-in-12-04). [Thinkwiki.org](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Integrated_Fingerprint_Reader) lists it as unsupported under Linux. It's discussed in [this development thread](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fprint/2012-November/000311.html).

Answer (score 2):

The answer in that article is for the x220. I have a x230 and fprint does not support yet the upek device used in it. So I guess it's waiting until they include support for it.

---

Linked Question:

- [How can I use my fingerprint reader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15029/how-can-i-use-my-fingerprint-reader#230013)

Answer (score 0):

The fprint library has been updated to support the finger print reader in the x230.

Get it here:
https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/a/236793/99751 here, i've solved it... sorry for the very late response.

I think It actually works out of the box in newer versions of Ubuntu.